# AngularJS - Handling Interval Persistence and Restart After Browser Reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Technology: **AngularJs**
**Requirement**: Call an API at a regular interval. The API will return tokens, which I've got to store in local storage.
To achieve this, I created a service called "refreshTokenService.js." I am starting the interval after a successful login. The code works properly until the browser is reloaded.

Problem: Once the browser is reloaded, the angular services get reset, and the interval is stopped. Hence, the refreshTokenService code won't execute.

Steps I followed.

1. From the login controller, after successful login, I'm emitting "isUserLoggedIn" which is received in mainCtroller.js to start the interval. 
   mainCtroller.js Code:

```
    $rootScope.$on('isUserLoggedIn', function(){
                if($localStorage.token)
                    refreshService.startInterval();
            });    
 
    $rootScope.$on('refreshTokenStop', function(){
                    refreshService.stopInterval();
                });
```

refreshService.js Code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    app.service('refreshService', refreshServiceFunction);
    refreshServiceFunction.$inject = ['$rootScope','$http','$interval','$localStorage'];

    function refreshServiceFunction($rootScope,$http,$interval,$localStorage) {
        var tokenTime = 1000 * 60 * 1 ;
        var intervalStatus;
        
        function getRefreshToken(){
            console.log("Get Refresh Token Service Call ",new Date());
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: $rootScope.ctx + '/api/auth/refresh-token'
                }).then(function (response) {
                    
                    if(response.data.statusCode === 'Success'){
                        console.log("New Token generated ",new Date());
                        $localStorage.lastRefreshTime = new Date();
                        $localStorage.token = response.data.data;
                        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.data;
                    }else{
                        console.log("New Token generation failed ", response.data.message,new Date());
                    }       
                    
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error while Refresh Token call at time ",error,new Date());
                }); 
        }
            
        function startInterval() {
            intervalStatus = $interval(getRefreshToken, tokenTime );
        }
       function stopInterval() {
            if (intervalStatus) {
                $interval.cancel(intervalStatus);
            }
        }
        
        return {
            startInterval: startInterval,
            stopInterval: stopInterval
        };
    }
})();
```

To fix the issue of reloading the browser, I thought to reactivate the interval by calling it again once the browser is refreshed.
I choose to use '$stateChangeStart' as it is invoked every time, as shown in the below code:
main.js

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        if($localStorage.token){
            refreshService.startInterval();
        }
}
```

But there is a problem: the '$stateChangeStart' is invoked even while navigating the menu. So I can't know whether it is browser reload or just navigation (I don't want to do anything while navigation). Once browser reload is complete then activate the interval, calculate the remaning time if needed to trigger the API call.

I need a solution or any better approach to achieve the same.

Any help and guidance will be useful to me. Thanks in Advance.